# why a link with href starting with ms-apps:/// wil not be clickable

Tags: html, deep-linking, power-automate, powerapps

I have a Power Automate workflow which generated an email with this html body:-

```
<a href ='https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/c*******a/a/3***1?tenantId=b***9d&sourcetime=1701256244265?module=accident&id=95'>Link for desktop</a>
<a href ='ms-apps:///providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/3****b1?tenantId=b3****594c&restartApp=true&module=accident&id=95'>Link for mobile</a>
```

now the first link will be clickable while the other link will not be clickable, i thought that the issue might be from the power automate side or outlook, but even if I save this markup as HTML locally, I will get the same behavior.

any advice? i need the second link to implement deep linking inside power apps mobile application as per this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/mobile/mobile-deep-links#supported-urls-parameters-for-a-canvas-app

Thanks

Comment: Is it supposed to be a tripple slash?

Comment: @Pieterjan based on the doco, yes, it’s described with three slashes.

Comment: @Pieterjan i followed the documentation from microsoft

Comment: @Skin yes this what i can see also,,, could this by a typo inside the documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the second link isn’t clickable is because it uses a custom URI scheme (`ms-apps://`) that is not recognised by most browsers or email clients.

This scheme is only supported by the Power Apps mobile app which can launch the app specified by the link.

The suggestion is, and this is untested but, use a url shortener, like bitly, to redirect the user to the ms-apps link.

Given the nature of the link, it’s best to test it manually first and then if it works, generate the link via an API call.

https://dev.bitly.com/

Comment: maybe i can just provide the link as is without been inside `<a>` tag or this will not differ?

Comment: Maybe, all you need to do is try it and that will answer your question.

Comment: adding the link as-is will show as a clickable link on outlook mobile app but not on outlook desktop... atleast users using outlook mobile can get this working.. will try another approaches

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can provide both links, by just adding one liner "If this link doesn't work, click here" and add you second URL

Comment: @Sumit Singh yes i am sending both links, but i need the second link to be clickable. currently it will be clickable on outlook under IOS but not on outlook under android